# aligning equations without spacing

Tags: spacing, align, alignment

I have the following code:

```
\begin{align*}

&\mathbb{P}\bigl((X,\tilde{X})=(x,\tilde{x})_S,(Z,\tilde{Z})=(z,\tilde{z})_S\bigr)  \\

&=\mathbb{P}\bigl((Z,\tilde{Z}=(z,\tilde{z})_S\bigr)\,\mathbb{P}\bigl((X,\tilde{X})=(x,\tilde{x})_S\mid (Z,\tilde{Z})=(z,\tilde{z})_S\bigr)\\

&\!\begin{aligned}[t]

&=\mathbb{P}\bigl((Z,\tilde{Z}=(z,\tilde{z})_S\bigr)&&\prod_{j\in S}\bigl[\mathbb{P}(X_j=\tilde{x}_j\mid Z_j=\tilde{z}_j)\,\mathbb{P}(\tilde{X}_j=x_j\mid \tilde{Z}_j=z_j)\bigr]\\ 

&&\cdot&\prod_{j\notin S}\bigl[\mathbb{P}(X_j=x_j\mid Z_j=z_j)\,\mathbb{P}(\tilde{X}_j=\tilde{x}_j\mid \tilde{Z}_j=\tilde{z}_j)\bigr]\\

&=\mathbb{P}\bigl((Z,\tilde{Z}=(z,\tilde{z})_S\bigr)&&\prod_{j\in S}\bigl[f_j(\tilde{x}_j\mid\tilde{z}_j)f_j(x_j\mid z_j)\bigr]\\

&&\cdot&\prod_{j\notin S}\bigl[f_j(x_j\mid z_j)f_j(\tilde{x}_j\mid\tilde{z}_j)\bigr]\\

&=\mathbb{P}\bigl((Z,\tilde{Z}=(z,\tilde{z})_S\bigr)&&\prod_{j\in [p]}\bigl[f_j(\tilde{x}_j\mid\tilde{z}_j)f_j(x_j\mid z_j)\bigr]
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}
```

This is what I get:

[image]
I would like to align the big products with the correct spacing before them, but I can't do that!

Can anyone help me?
Thank you

Comment: Use `alignedat{2}`, not `aligned`.

Comment: You can use `aligned` but here I would use them on individual rows, thus have three of them, not just one, and I would have only one alignment point in each one.

Comment: Alignedat worked well. Thank you Bernard

Comment: please next time post a complete file (as in the answer) note also that you do not need `\!` before `aligned` unless your copy of `amsmath` is several years old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this looks good. I used an `aligned` environment in each line that is cut in two parts. I also adjusted the width of the subscript in the last product, because `[p]` is slightly larger than `S` so it messes up with the alignment a little.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{P}\bigl((X,\tilde{X})=(x,\tilde{x})_S,(Z,\tilde{Z})=(z,\tilde{z})_S\bigr)  \\
& = \mathbb{P}\bigl((Z,\tilde{Z}=(z,\tilde{z})_S\bigr)\,\mathbb{P}\bigl((X,\tilde{X})=(x,\tilde{x})_S\mid (Z,\tilde{Z})=(z,\tilde{z})_S\bigr) \\
& = \begin{aligned}[t]
    \mathbb{P}\bigl((Z,\tilde{Z}=(z,\tilde{z})_S\bigr) & \prod_{j\in S}\bigl[\mathbb{P}(X_j=\tilde{x}_j\mid Z_j=\tilde{z}_j)\,\mathbb{P}(\tilde{X}_j=x_j\mid \tilde{Z}_j=z_j)\bigr] \\ 
    \cdot & \prod_{j\notin S}\bigl[\mathbb{P}(X_j=x_j\mid Z_j=z_j)\,\mathbb{P}(\tilde{X}_j=\tilde{x}_j\mid \tilde{Z}_j=\tilde{z}_j)\bigr]
\end{aligned} \\
& = \begin{aligned}[t] 
    \mathbb{P}\bigl((Z,\tilde{Z}=(z,\tilde{z})_S\bigr) & \prod_{j\in S}\bigl[f_j(\tilde{x}_j\mid\tilde{z}_j)f_j(x_j\mid z_j)\bigr] \\
    \cdot & \prod_{j\notin S}\bigl[f_j(x_j\mid z_j)f_j(\tilde{x}_j\mid\tilde{z}_j)\bigr]
\end{aligned} \\
& = \mathbb{P}\bigl((Z,\tilde{Z}=(z,\tilde{z})_S\bigr) \prod_{\makebox[\widthof{\(\scriptstyle j\in S\)}]{\(\scriptstyle j\in [p]\)}}\bigl[f_j(\tilde{x}_j\mid\tilde{z}_j)f_j(x_j\mid z_j)\bigr]
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wonderful! I couldn't see the difference between those subscripts. Thank you, Vincent